# When will boost.asio actually start the transmission and send the data?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` uses buffers. I know that when `write` or `async_write` is called, the data is just written into the buffers. My question is when will them be actually sent? Or, to be more precise, when will asio actually start the transmission?

From what I know, at least, asio must start the transmission when the buffer is full, so the data can be considered sent in this case. But, what if there's no more data put into the buffer? Will short data stay in the buffer forever? Do I need to call some `flush()` APIs to tell asio that *"There's no more for now. Send the data in the buffer right away!"* ? If there are no such APIs, how can I ensure the timeliness of transmission?

Comment: This question is not about previous questions about message splitting, terminators, or something else. This one is about timeliness.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

Comment: Asio's socket.write is not using internal buffers, it is transferring the data in the buffers that you provide directly to kernel space. The kernel sends out the data according to Nagle's algorithm, as linked in the other comment.

Comment: As others have indicated, this is property of the IP stack (kernel/driver) and has nothing specifically to do with asio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank user7860670, Jakob Stark and sehe for their comments. To summarize:

1. Asio has no additional buffer mechanisms beyond those in the OS kernel.
2. The OS kernel uses Nagle's algorithm normally, which promise that data is sent within a finite time frame.
3. To improve the timeliness, use `TCP_NODELAY`, which is available as [`boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/no_delay.html) in Asio.

Comment: +1 from me. It might have been a naive question to some, but it makes total sense for others to have the same highlevel question, and as such fits the objective of this Q&A site. I guess any duplicates would be on another site https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3054/packet-sizes-in-a-tcp-stream/3060#3060